# Apache Rewrite !-f !-d But Allow File In Dotted Folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, lets-encrypt

I have a web site that redirects all nonfolders and files to an index.php script, like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q={$1} [L,QSA]
```

But, I am using letsencrypt, and would like to be able to access a file directly to confirm the SSL cert.  The file path would be:

```
http://example.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/ReGasdfq8is_ogwLaQzd42QH49qZJwgasdfVEnoOJSk
```

When I try to access that path, it is being redirected to the index.php script and not displaying the contents of the `ReGasdfq8is_ogwLaQzd42QH49qZJwgasdfVEnoOJSk` file.

Is that because the .well-known folder is dotted?  Can I allow access to the dotted folder?

Comment: I am aware of the fact that I could temporarily comment the rewrite code, but I am looking for a more permanent solution, as I don't want to break the operation of the site even for a short period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(/.well-known)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q={$1} [L,QSA]
```

(Edited by Dave to add slash and remove space - to reflect working solution)

Comment: I got `RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters` until I removed the space between !^ and (.well-known).  But I removed that space, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Got it! Needed to add a slash, like so: `RewriteCond $1 !^(/.well-known)`.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dave Thank you I'll update my answer If i can keep from messing it up to match the proper condition